# Oracle SQL Check if value exists based only on Start and End

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following table

TABLE1

| BATCH_FROM_N | REG_N_START | BATCH_TO_N | PREF_REG_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000000 | CAL0001 | 5000019 | CAL |
| 5000050 | CAL0031 | 5000059 | CAL |
| 5000100 | CAL0299 | 5000105 | CAL |

Line 1 will generate 20 REG_N's as `CAL0001,CAL0002,CAL0003,CAL0004,CAL0005,CAL0006,CAL0007,CAL0008,CAL0009,CAL0010,CAL0011,CAL0012,CAL0013,CAL0014,CAL0015,CAL0016,CAL0017,CAL0018,CAL0019,CAL0020`

Line 2 will generate 10 REG_N's as `CAL0031,CAL0032,CAL0033,CAL0034,CAL0035,CAL0036,CAL0037,CAL0038,CAL0039,CAL0040`

Line 3 will generate 6 REG_N's as `CAL0299,CAL0300,CAL0301,CAL0302,CAL0303,CAL0304`

Given a New Range (Start & End) that a user will try to capture, I need to see if any REG_NUM exists in the table above and PASS/FAIL as follows :

Expected result

| NEW_REG_NUM_FROM | NEW_REG_NUM_TO | RESULT_EXPECTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAL0006 | CAL0008 | FAIL |
| CAL0019 | CAL0025 | FAIL |
| CAL0025 | CAL0025 | PASS |
| CAL0025 | CAL0027 | PASS |
| CAL0027 | CAL0036 | FAIL |
| CAL0100 | CAL0300 | FAIL |
| CAL0100 | CAL0200 | PASS |

I have tried this SQL, but it will obviously fail:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   TABLE1
WHERE  TABLE1.REG_N_START <= NEW_REG_NUM_TO
AND    TABLE1.REG_N_START >= NEW_REG_NUM_FROM;
```

Comment: Hi one way you con do is the following steps.  1)  You calculate the difference between BATCH_FROM_N and BATCH_TO_N . 2) Take a substr of REG_N_START, the last 4 character "0001" and add the number that you got in the step 1.  3) When inserting see if the the last 4 characters/numbers fall in this range and mark that row as Pass or Fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the initial table to ranges and then look for overlaps:

```sql
WITH new_data (NEW_REG_NUM_FROM, NEW_REG_NUM_TO) AS (
  SELECT 'CAL0006', 'CAL0008' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAL0019', 'CAL0025' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAL0025', 'CAL0025' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAL0025', 'CAL0027' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAL0027', 'CAL0036' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAL0100', 'CAL0300' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAL0100', 'CAL0200' FROM DUAL
),
t1_ranges (reg_n_start, reg_n_end) AS (
  SELECT reg_n_start,
         pref_reg_n
         || LPAD(
              TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_n_start, LENGTH(pref_reg_n) + 1))
                + batch_to_n - batch_from_n,
              4,
             '0'
            )
  FROM   table1
)
SELECT n.*,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   t1_ranges t
              WHERE  t.reg_n_start <= n.new_reg_num_to
              AND    n.new_reg_num_from <= t.reg_n_end   
            )
       THEN 'FAIL'
       ELSE 'PASS'
       END AS result
FROM   new_data n
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (BATCH_FROM_N, REG_N_START, BATCH_TO_N, PREF_REG_N) AS
SELECT 5000000, 'CAL0001', 5000019, 'CAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5000050, 'CAL0031', 5000059, 'CAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5000100, 'CAL0299', 5000105, 'CAL' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NEW_REG_NUM_FROM | NEW_REG_NUM_TO | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAL0006 | CAL0008 | FAIL |
| CAL0019 | CAL0025 | FAIL |
| CAL0025 | CAL0025 | PASS |
| CAL0025 | CAL0027 | PASS |
| CAL0027 | CAL0036 | FAIL |
| CAL0100 | CAL0300 | FAIL |
| CAL0100 | CAL0200 | PASS |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab8f03/5)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like the below:

```
with tb (new_regnum_from, new_regnum_to) as (
  select 'CAL0006', 'CAL0008' from dual union all
  select 'CAL0019', 'CAL0025' from dual union all
  select 'CAL0025', 'CAL0025' from dual union all   
  select 'CAL0025',     'CAL0027' from dual 
)
,tb_intervs as (
select reg_start_n, batch_to_n, batch_from_n
  ,subsr(reg_start_n,1,length(pref_reg_n)) ||
    lpad(to_char((substr(reg_start_n,length(pref_reg_n)+1,100)+batch_to_n-batch_from_n),length(reg_start_n)-length(pref_reg_n),'0') upper_lim_n
from table1
)
select new_regnum_from, new_regnum_to  
  ,case
    when exists (
      select 1
      from tb_intervs t1 
      where4 (new_regnum_from between t1.reg_start_n and t1.upper_lim_n) 
        or (new_regnum_to between t1.reg_start_n and t1.upper_lim_n)
      ) then 'FAIL'
    else 'PASS'
  end test_result
from tb
```

;

I haven't actually tested though...
The first thing to test would be the returns of:

```
select reg_start_n, batch_to_n, batch_from_n
  ,subsr(reg_start_n,1,length(pref_reg_n)) ||
    lpad(to_char((substr(reg_start_n,length(pref_reg_n)+1,100)+batch_to_n-batch_from_n),length(reg_start_n)-length(pref_reg_n),'0') upper_lim_n
from table1m_n
```

There may be some errors in this select used as CTE...
Hope this will help.
Eventually create a view for what I sued as CTE named tb_intervs.

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid (`where4` and `subsr` are just typos but if you fix those then you get `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`). Even if you fix that then I think you will get an incorrect answer for the new data `SELECT 'CAL0100', 'CAL0500' FROM DUAL` as neither of those values are contained in any range but it does completely overlap the final row in `table1` and should give the output `FAIL`.